# Anime about a blue-haired AI with a plasma cannon on her arm, who broke her programming to save her master

Tags: story-identification, anime

The plot was that this blue haired AI was a prototype with a plasma cannon on her arm, and she became a servant of this guy and eventually fell in love. She broke her programming to save him.

She had sisters, one who was small and threw flower petals that exploded, and another sister who had a sword.

Comment: Hi there! Coul you maybe [edit] in some more info, like when you saw it, the channel it aired on, if it was in English? Take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/98028) on anime-id questions to check what you could add: the more info, the greater the chance of a successful ID!

Comment: This kind of sounds like Miyu from Mai-Hime. She is an android / cyborg who has blue hair and these abilities, and attends a school with gifted people called HiMEs. She eventually breaks her programming.

Answer (score -2):

I think you may be thinking of *Sora no Otoshimono*.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/5958/Sora_no_Otoshimono):

> Ever since he was a child, Tomoki Sakurai has always woke up with tears after a dream of an angel. His childhood friend Sohara Mitsuki worries about this and decides to seek the help of Eishirou Sugata, an eccentric sky maniac. He concludes that Tomoki's dream is undoubtedly connected to what is known as the New World, a floating anomaly that scientists have failed to understand.
>
> Recruiting the New World Discovery Club's first members, Eishirou schedules a time to meet up in order to observe the mystery in the sky. That day, Tomoki's peaceful life is changed forever when a strange girl falls from the sky and begins to call him master.
>
> *Sora no Otoshimono* follows the daily activities of the New World Discovery Club as they begin to learn more about the Angeloids that have arrived on Earth.

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain why you think this matches the OP's description?

Comment: Hmm... I don't see a bluehaired girl, a plasma arm cannon, or the sisters with those capabilities.

Comment: In the US, this was renamed [Heaven's Lost Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Lost_Property). But I agree, this doesn't seem to fit the described series

Comment: the anime name was called beatless.